# How do I print random passwords every time I run through a for loop

Tags: python

Hello right now I have been working on a password generator. I want to be able to get many passwords from one run. Instead of having to run the code multiple times. Right now the code asks the user how many passwords they want then they get those passwords. But I have a for loop set up to do this, and it gives the same pass word x amount of times. But i want it to give me a diffrent password x amount of times

Heres the code:

```
    import random

upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQURSTUVWXYZ"

lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqurstuvwxyz"
numbers = "1234567890"
symbols = "!@#$%^&*()"

string = upper + lower + numbers + symbols
length = 16

password = "".join(random.sample(string, length))

passNum = int(input("How many passwords do you want?: "))

for i in range(passNum):
    print("Your new password is: " + password)
```

Comment: make sure to compute `password` again each time, i.e. do it _inside_ the loop body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the `password` in the loop, not once before

```
passNum = int(input("How many passwords do you want?: "))
for i in range(passNum):
    password = "".join(random.sample(string, length))
    print("Your new password is: " + password)
```

Note that `sample` generates a unique combination of the given values, to make N independent pick, use `choices` (does N `choice`)

---

Note the `string` package contains the character lists

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits

symbols = "!@#$%^&*()"
values = ascii_letters, digits + symbols
```

There is also `punctuation` but is way larger than your symbols

```
# from string import punctuation 
punctuation = r"""!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"""
```

Answer (score 2):

Right now, you are only creating one password. You need to add the `password = ...` line to your loop so that you create a new password with each iteration.

```
import random

upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQURSTUVWXYZ"

lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqurstuvwxyz"
numbers = "1234567890"
symbols = "!@#$%^&*()"

string = upper + lower + numbers + symbols
length = 16



passNum = int(input("How many passwords do you want?: "))

for i in range(passNum):
  password = "".join(random.sample(string, length))
  print("Your new password is: " + password)
```